# HBASE row prefix scan in reverse order in hbase

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

I have a row key of the form:

```
<name>--<zero-padded timestamp>
```

Using HBASE shell I want to find last 15 entries with the prefix .

```
scan 'mytable', {LIMIT => 15, ROWPREFIXFILTER => 'name' }
```

Gives me the first 15, but:

```
scan 'mytable', {LIMIT => 15, REVERSED => TRUE, ROWPREFIXFILTER => 'name'}
```

returns zero results...

What is the syntax for such a request?

Is it possible, or do I have to do something cheesy like use MAXINT-timestamp as my rowkey to manually reverse the key ordering?

Comment: what version of HBase? Can you show us some sample data from your table?

Comment: VERSION 1.2.2. The data is just log entries. I want to pull them out in reverse timestamp order is all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can execute your query command in HBase shell environment, and get the expected result. But couldn't get any result throw Java Client. My HBase version is 0.98.

There is a bug when use HBase client scan with reversed = true, see this jira issue [hbase-client: scanner with reversed=true and small=true get no result](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-16886?jql=project%20%3D%20HBASE)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I reproduced this issue, and my result was the same.

The workaround I used was to change `ROWPREFILTER` to `STARTROW` and `ENDROW`.