# Hbase reverse scan

Tags: java, hbase

My data keys are stored in format `trade<date><index>`

```
trade1907030001
trade1907030002
trade1907040001
trade1907040002
trade1907050001
trade1907050002
```

What is proper way to implement 'reverse' scan to iterate over all trades for the day or from specific row down to the end of the day or even between two exact trades?

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setReversed(true);
scan.setStartRow(Bytes.unsignedCopyAndIncrement(Bytes.toBytes(trade + day)));
scan.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytes(trade + day));
```

Having in mind that according to documentatin start row is inclusive and end row is exclusive, we'll miss oldest trade of the day. If the row is actually the trade row trade we must not increment the key, otherwise next trade will be picked up. It started to be conditional. How could I make it work reliable for different situations?

Comment: HBase javadoc states that there are two methods for specifying stop row: 1. public Scan withStopRow(byte[] stopRow); 2. public Scan withStopRow(byte[] stopRow, boolean inclusive); - probably the second one is what you need

Comment: or maybe you may specify "day minus 0" for start and "day minus 1" for stop

Comment: many new things in HBase 3.0, apperently I'm using old one (

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HBASE row prefix scan in reverse order in hbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772832/hbase-row-prefix-scan-in-reverse-order-in-hbase). Looks like there was a bug on the older version you're using, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is how scan actually works (tested in hbase shell v1.2.0-cdh5.13.3):

```
trade171020S00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511793438335, value=20171020
trade171018B00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511793438335, value=20171020
trade171020S00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511793438335, value=20171020
trade171113B00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511993729979, value=20171114
trade171114S00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511993729979, value=20171114

scan 'namespace:table', {COLUMNS=>['inp:data_as_of_date'], STARTROW=>'trade171018B00001', ENDROW=>'trade171113B00001'}
ROW                                                                  COLUMN+CELL
trade171018B00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511793438335, value=20171020
trade171020S00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511793438335, value=20171020

scan 'namespace:table', {COLUMNS=>['inp:data_as_of_date'], STARTROW=>'trade171113B00001', ENDROW=>'trade171018B00001', REVERSED=>true}
ROW                                                                  COLUMN+CELL
trade171113B00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511993729979, value=20171114
trade171020S00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511793438335, value=20171020

scan 'namespace:table', {COLUMNS=>['inp:data_as_of_date'], STARTROW=>'trade171018', ENDROW=>'trade171113'}
ROW                                                                  COLUMN+CELL
trade171018B00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511793438335, value=20171020
trade171020S00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511793438335, value=20171020

scan 'namespace:table', {COLUMNS=>['inp:data_as_of_date'], STARTROW=>'trade171113', ENDROW=>'trade171018', REVERSED=>true}
ROW                                                                  COLUMN+CELL
trade171020S00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511793438335, value=20171020
trade171018B00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511793438335, value=20171020

scan 'namespace:table', {COLUMNS=>['inp:data_as_of_date'], ROWPREFIXFILTER=>'trade171113'}
ROW                                                                  COLUMN+CELL
trade171113B00001                                          column=inp:data_as_of_date, timestamp=1511993729979, value=20171114

scan 'namespace:table', {COLUMNS=>['inp:data_as_of_date'], ROWPREFIXFILTER=>'trade171113', REVERSED=>true}
ROW                                                                  COLUMN+CELL
0 row(s) in 0.2300 seconds
```

**If start row and end row is shorter then table row keys**, following will work as expected

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytes(trade + day));
scan.setStopRow(Bytes.unsignedCopyAndIncrement(Bytes.toBytes(trade + day)));

Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setReversed(true);
scan.setStartRow(Bytes.unsignedCopyAndIncrement(Bytes.toBytes(trade + day)));
scan.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytes(trade + day));
```

**If start row and end row could be same length as table row keys**, following will work as expected

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setStartRow(createKey("S", productSymbolId, YYMMDD.print(fromDate)));
scan.setStopRow(createNextKey("S", productSymbolId, YYMMDD.print(toDate)));

Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setReversed(true);
scan.setStartRow(createKeyBeforeNext("A", stripSpaces(accountId), YYMMDD.print(toDate)));
scan.setStopRow(createKeyBefore("A", stripSpaces(accountId), YYMMDD.print(fromDate)));
```

where

```
key === 54686973697361746573746b6579
next === 54686973697361746573746b657a
before === 54686973697361746573746b6578ffffffffffffffffff
beforeNext === 54686973697361746573746b6579ffffffffffffffffff
```

implementation

```
/**
 * <h4>usage</h4>
 * 
 * <pre>
 * Scan scan = new Scan();
 * scan.setStartRow(createKey("S", productSymbolId, YYMMDD.print(fromDate)));
 * scan.setStopRow(createNextKey("S", productSymbolId, YYMMDD.print(toDate)));
 *
 * Scan scan = new Scan();
 * scan.setReversed(true);
 * scan.setStartRow(createKeyBeforeNext("A", stripSpaces(accountId), YYMMDD.print(toDate)));
 * scan.setStopRow(createKeyBefore("A", stripSpaces(accountId), YYMMDD.print(fromDate)));
 * </pre>
 * 
 * <h4>spec</h4>
 * 
 * <pre>
 * key === 54686973697361746573746b6579
 * next === 54686973697361746573746b657a
 * before === 54686973697361746573746b6578ffffffffffffffffff
 * beforeNext === 54686973697361746573746b6579ffffffffffffffffff
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @see #createKeyBefore(String...)
 * @see #createKeyBeforeNext(String...)
 * @see #createNextKey(String...)
 */
// similar to Bytes.add(final byte [] a, final byte [] b, final byte [] c) {
public static byte[] createKey(String... parts) {
    byte[][] bytes = new byte[parts.length][];
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = toBytes(parts[i]);
        size += bytes[i].length;
    }
    byte[] result = new byte[size];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        arraycopy(bytes[i], 0, result, j, bytes[i].length);
        j += bytes[i].length;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Create the next row
 * 
 * <pre>
 * key === 54686973697361746573746b6579
 * next === 54686973697361746573746b657a
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @see #createKey(String...)
 */
public static byte[] createNextKey(String... parts) {
    return unsignedCopyAndIncrement(createKey(parts));
}

/**
 * Create the closest row before
 * 
 * <pre>
 * key === 54686973697361746573746b6579
 * before === 54686973697361746573746b6578ffffffffffffffffff
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @see #createKey(String...)
 */
public static byte[] createKeyBefore(String... parts) {
    return createClosestRowBefore(createKey(parts));
}

/**
 * Create the closest row before the next row
 * 
 * <pre>
 * key === 54686973697361746573746b6579
 * beforeNext === 54686973697361746573746b6579ffffffffffffffffff
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @see #createKey(String...)
 */
public static byte[] createKeyBeforeNext(String... parts) {
    return createClosestRowBefore(createNextKey(parts));
}

// from hbase sources ClientScanner.createClosestRowBefore(byte[] row)
private static byte[] createClosestRowBefore(byte[] row) {
    if (row == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The passed row is empty");
    if (Bytes.equals(row, HConstants.EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY))
        return MAX_BYTE_ARRAY;
    if (row[row.length - 1] == 0)
        return Arrays.copyOf(row, row.length - 1);
    byte[] closestFrontRow = Arrays.copyOf(row, row.length);
    closestFrontRow[row.length - 1] = (byte) ((closestFrontRow[row.length - 1] & 0xff) - 1);
    closestFrontRow = Bytes.add(closestFrontRow, MAX_BYTE_ARRAY);
    return closestFrontRow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setReversed(true);
scan.setRowPrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(trade + day));
```

which automatically takes cares of ensuring the first and last trades aren't ignored.

Source: https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setRowPrefixFilter-byte:A-

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I changed my code and unit tests for 'backward scan' failed. Something is not that simple here or maybe a bug in older HBase client.

Comment: What version of HBase are you running against? This method is quite old (and its behaviour hasn't changed).

Comment: Actually I've reproduced it in command line, see my updated answer. Version 1.2.0-cdh5.13.3